# Ruby subclass namespacing with parent class

Tags: ruby, inheritance, namespaces

Is it valid and/or acceptable to use a class for namespacing as opposed to a module? Maybe it's just a matter of opinion, but I thought someone might have experience with this that could say definitively whether or not it's an accepted practice.

Take the following classes for example:

```
class Parent
end

class Parent::Child1 < Parent
end

class Parent::Child2 < Parent
end
```

I know the above code works, but it seems weird to use a class instead of a module for the namespace. The reason I want to add the parent class name to the subclass is because I plan on having a lot of subclasses and want to avoid name conflicts. For example:

```
class Priority
end

class Priority::Low < Priority
end

class Temperature
end

class Temperature::Low < Priority
end
```

The alternative to this would be to not use namespaces and just use the parent name as part of the subclass name:

```
class PriorityLow < Priority
end
```

Is there a best practice for namespacing in Ruby?

**Update:**

@sawa asked below for some examples. It's for a Gem that I built called [classy_enum](https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum) which allows users to define classes that are members of an Enum type. Check out the [example usage section](https://github.com/beerlington/classy_enum#example-usage) for a little more background on it. I am cleaning up the code base and it occurred to me that my suggested naming scheme could be improved. So instead of using `PriorityLow`, you could use `Priority::Low` (or whatever makes the most sense, but I'm leaning toward the latter)

Comment: Maybe if you show examples of the methods to be included, that might make the issue clearer. And the answer might depend on that.

Comment: @sawa I updated the question with my use case

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't have a definitive answer, but it seems worth noting that the Ruby `Class` class is a subclass of `Module`, which means to me that a Class is a type of Module, which suggests that it's probably reasonable to do what you want.  I certainly can't see any reason to avoid it, though I'm curious to see if anyone comes up with any potential downsides.

Comment: No need to be so hesitant. Classes are Modules, and Modules are used for namespacing. This approach is certainly more elegant than any other I can think of.

Comment: Thanks for the input. This has been my hunch, but I'm going to leave it open a little longer just to see if anyone has any other suggestions.

Comment: I updated my question with some notes about my use case. Not sure it will have an effect on your answer or not.

Comment: @Beerlington Looking at classy_enum, I can see why you want to do this. I think it's definitely cleaner and clearer to have the subclasses use the superclass as a namespace, as you propose. I still can't come up with a reason not to.